# Can I write Selenium EdgeDriver tests on Windows 7 IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, browserstack, selenium-edgedriver

I am running Selenium WebDriver tests in the BrowserStack Automate grid. I am writing tests on a Windows 7 machine. I don't seem to be able to download and install the Edge WebDriver.

All instructions seem to point to downloading and installing Windows 10 first. This kind of makes sense if I wanted to run the tests locally - but not when I want to run them in a grid.

Are there any work arounds?

Comment: I think you answered your own question to use Grid configuration on Browserstack. What else work around are you looking for?

Comment: perhaps some wrapper libs that will allow us to use EdgeDriver on Win7?